# Is "execute app as me" deployment setting secure?

Tags: security, google-apps-script, deployment, web-applications, permissions

I'm currently creating a simple script that is essentially just a form that people can fill out an upload a couple of files.

When I click `Deploy as a Web App`, one of the form items asks "Execute the app as". One of the options is: Me (example@gmail.com)

Is this safe?

Does that mean anyone who has a link to the script essentially becomes logged in to my account?

Are there security risks to this?

[image: deployment screen]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the most important issues is, who has access to the Apps Script ***file***.  The file sharing settings are set totally differently than the web app deployment settings.  You can have the Apps Script file *SHARED* settings, set to **not being shared with anyone**, and *still* have anyone be able to access the web app.  So, access to the **web app**, and access to the **file** are two different things.  That's a key point to understand.

The **Execute the app as** *me*, is not inherently unsecure.  It doesn't log someone into your account.  ***IF*** you somehow configured your app to give broad access to your account, which you can do, that's obviously a potential security hole.  You should set scopes manually in the appsscript.json manifest file that are more restricted.  For example, restricted scopes to your Gmail and Drive if the Web App sends an email, or accesses your Google Drive.  You can restrict the email scope to only be able to send an email, and restrict the Drive scope to only be able to access files and folders that the script created, or that the user picked with the Google file picker.  You can restrict access to only the current spreadsheet, instead of all your spreadsheets.

Are there potential security holes? Yes.  But there aren't any security holes that you wouldn't have with *any* web app.  So, it's really dependent upon the practices you use.

Don't use/store settings/parameters in client side HTML, that directly cause a server function to perform an action that you don't want anyone to be able to execute.

How secure your app is depends on some simple practices.

Don't store settings or information in HTML that could cause a security hole.  Passwords is the obvious example.  Don't put names of files in HTML code.  Don't pass settings or parameters in Client side calls to the server that are obviously a direct link to a server function that has broad access to your account.

You can put an underbar at the end of server side function names so that a user can't know the names of your server function.

[https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#private_functions](http://Private%20Functions)

Have a main server function that then calls a private function, that in turn branches to other functions.  So the user will never know the name of the function that is ultimately doing all the real work.

Answer (score 0):

If someone else has access to modify your Script, then yes, he can re-publish the app that will have access to whatever you previously authorized, but won't have new authorizations. Eg, if you used only SpreadsheetApp as your first code and authorized it, someone who has access to modify this script you already published can open all your Spreadsheets and erase them, but wont be able to touch the Docs.

Someone with the published app URL will have none of this, it will only run the scripts you/shared scripters published.

I use "Me"/"Anyone Even Anonymous" quite frequently, published dozens of apps and never had any issue.

Comment: So if I use `Spreadsheets` in my script, anyone with permissions to modify the script can delete all my spreadhseets?

Comment: Not the actual spreadsheet, since there is no setTrashed in SpreadsheetApp, only in the file class, but he can delete/retrieve/play with all content of all sheets at will, if you let it have the DriveApp scope then yes, he can delete all and any file with setTrashed, but it will go to the trash can, don't know if it can be permanently unrecoverable. To see what has already been authorised in "File" > "Project properties" > "Scopes". Tough by SpreadsheetApp he can't search for the sheet, he must know the ID of it, which can be retrieved from a URL.

Comment: note that none of your concerns apply to someone with the published script url. only if they have access to the actual script file (or comtainer sheet of any) which wasnt your concern in the question.